# Strange error value in input box not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using Ui Kitten in react native for UI theme.

```
<Input value={this.state.total}  /> // doesn't show the value

<Input value="1"  /> // now shows the value

<Input value={console.log(this.state.total)}  /> // returns 1 in log
```

Why input box is not showing value from state... what can be the error ?

Comment: Maybe covert it to `String` ?

Comment: correct.. it was String Issue... Thank u...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it as `<Input value={this.state.total.toString()}  />` and solved. Input value field was taking only string value, and i was passing integer.